# java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: jdk.proxy2.$Proxy40.proxyClassLookup()

Tags: java, automation, appium, ui-automation, appium-ios

I am getting the error message "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: jdk.proxy2.$Proxy40.proxyClassLookup()" when running a test from the command line using the command "-Dtest=ms.testProject.tests.package1.testClass#test1"

```
<compiler.version>1.8</compiler.version>
<maven.surefire.version>3.0.0-M5</maven.surefire.version>
<maven.compiler.version>3.8.1</maven.compiler.version>
<appium.version>7.6.0</appium.version>
<testng.version>7.3.0</testng.version>
```

```
public BasePage(AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver) {
    PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), this);
    this.driver = driver;
}
```

I am using @iOSXCUITFindBy annotations

jDK 1.8

I tried changing the JDK version, Maven-Surefire, but nothing helped. When upgrading the Appium version, old annotations are no longer supported, and there are several related issues. Please share your solutions if you have experienced similar problems

Answer (score 0):

Use `PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);`

instead of `PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver),
this);

Also import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy instead of iOSXCUITFindBy

This worked for me.